# XMLHTTPRequest, C# calling a single method in the code behind?

Tags: c#, xmlhttprequest

I'm using xhr for a file uploader, for opening the connection I have:

xhr.open('POST', 'ProgressTest.aspx/UploadFile', true);

However, this does not hit the UploadFile method when I debug, it always hits Page_Load in ProgressTest.aspx which is not what I want. I have UploadFile attributed with [WebMethod]. Is there something that I am missing here?

Comment: Hi @user6050770, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

In order for ASP.NET to invoke a web method, the request must have a Content-Type of 'application/json'.  The following javascript code should fix your problem:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'ProgressTest.aspx/UploadFile', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
xhr.send();
```

Also, be sure to make the C# method static, or ASP.NET won't be able to find it.